# How can you export a MySQL database, representing binary data with X'val' rather than 0xval hex notation?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, h2

I have a MySQL database used by a Java application.  Primary keys are all UUID values, stored with the `BINARY(16)` data type.

When I dump this database using `mysqldump`, or Data Export within MySQL Workbench, I use the `--hex-blob` option.  My binary UUID values get dumped in this format:

`0xCA283225D32C45579047517BDFF99174`

For testing, I would like to load these dumps into an embedded H2 database (running in "MySQL compatibility" mode).  The problem is that even in "compatibility" mode, H2 **only** accepts hex literals in the format:

`X'CA283225D32C45579047517BDFF99174'`

Since H2 has this limitation, but MySQL can accept either format, I would like to simply use the `X'val'` format exclusively.  However, I don't see an obvious way to make `mysqldump` or MySQL Workbench apply this convention.

Is it possible to do so?  Or are you forced into a more hacky solution, like writing a script to convert the values after-the-fact via regex or something?

Answer (score 0):

H2 accepts non-standard `0x`-prefixed literals as binary string literals in MySQL and MSSQLServer compatibility modes only since H2 1.4.200; you need to upgrade your version.

Comment: Are you SURE that functionality has been committed and released?  I am indeed using version 1.4.200.  At the time of this comment, that is the most recent version, and has only been out for a couple of months.  So any such added support was VERY recently developed, and I'm not sure it's actually out yet.

Comment: Yes, it was implemented in May 2019 and included into 1.4.200. But you need to use a compatibility mode by appending `;MODE=MySQL` to the connection URL or with `SET MODE MySQL` command. How exactly the error message that you see looks like? Without a compatibility mode cast to `BINARY(16)` in H2 1.4.200 throws an exception with `[90003-200] 90003/90003` in the end, where `-200` indicates a database version.